# spark flatmap - scala to java code

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have been practising spark. I am not very familiar with scala and want to try the java code.  For the below basic operations of map and flatmap, how do i write the below code in java

```
sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3)).flatMap(x=>List(x,x,x)).collect
sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3)).map(x=>List(x,x,x)).collect
```

Comment: Which java version are you using?

Answer (score -1):

It's basically the same:

```
sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(1,2,3)).flatMap(x->Arrays.asList(x,x,x).iterator()).collect();
sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(1,2,3)).map(x->Arrays.asList(x,x,x)).collect();
```

where `sc` is a [`JavaSparkContext`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html) (and assuming you use Java 8 and Spark 2.0.0).

Comment: I get the compilation error "bad return type in lambda expression. [ERROR] java.util.Iterator<java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to java.lang.Iterable<U>)"

Comment: The code I gave should work for Spark 2.0.0, for previous versions remove `iterator()`.